# How to attach a div to the side of a div positioned via margin: auto 0;

Tags: css, html, positioning

I have what is a fairly common page layout where the content div is centralised on the page using `margin:auto 0`. The width of the div itself varies depending on available page width.

I want another div featuring a logo to 'stick' to the outside left hand side of this div (ie no gap or overlap between the two) at a fixed height. What CSS should I use for this?

Comment: @NabilKadimi No, I don't.  Please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/why-what-stack-overflow-is-not-was-deleted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

html:

```
<html>
    <div id='content'>
        <div id='stickything'>a</div>
    </div>
</html>
```

css:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: green;
}

#stickything {
    position: fixed;
    width: 25px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kkcnn/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute`. It must help:

```
.container-div{ 
position: relative 
}

.outer-div{
position:absolute;
top: 0 (your choice)
left: -/outer div's width/
}
```